# Reading an Input File And Store The Data Into an Array (beginner)!

Tags: c++, arrays, string, iostream, ifstream

The Input file:

```
1 4 red
2 0 blue
3 1 white
4 2 green
5 2 black
```

what I want to do is take every row and store it into 2D array.
for example:

```
array[0][0] = 1
array[0][1] = 4
array[0][2] = red
array[1][0] = 2
array[1][1] = 0
array[1][2] = blue
etc..
```

code Iam working on it:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream> 
    #include <string>
    #include <sstream>
    #include <vector>

    using namespace std;

    int convert_str_to_int(const string& str) {
        int val;
        stringstream ss;
        ss << str;
        ss >> val;
        return val;
    }


    string getid(string str){

        istringstream  iss(str);
        string pid;
        iss >> pid;
        return pid;
    }
    string getnumberofcolors(string str){
        istringstream  iss(str);
        string pid,c;
        iss >> pid>>c;
        return c;
    }

    int main() {
        string lineinfile ;
        vector<string> lines;

        ifstream infile("myinputfile.txt"); 
        if ( infile ) {
            while ( getline( infile , lineinfile ) ) {
            lines.push_back(lineinfile);
            }
        }
        //first line - number of items
        int numofitems = convert_str_to_int(lines[0]);

        //lopps items info 
        string ar[numofitems ][3];
        int i = 1;

        while(i<=numofitems ){
            ar[i][0] = getid(lines[i]);
            i++;
        }
        while(i<=numofitems ){
            ar[i][1] = getarrivel(lines[i]);
            i++;
        }

        infile.close( ) ;
        return 0 ;
    }
```

when I add the second while loop my program stopped working for some reason!
is there any other way to to this or a solution to my program to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to show you how to do it much better:

```
#include <fstream> 
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream infile("myinputfile.txt");  // Streams skip spaces and line breaks

    //first line - number of items
    size_t numofitems;
    infile >> numofitems;

    //lopps items info 
    vector<pair<int, pair<int, string>> ar(numofitems); // Or use std::tuple

    for(size_t i = 0; i < numofitems; ++i){
        infile >> ar[i].first >> ar[i].second.first >> ar[i].second.second;
    }

    // infile.close( ) ; // Not needed -- closed automatically
    return 0 ;
}
```

You are probably solving some kind of simple algorithmic task. Take a look at `std::pair` and `std::tuple`, which are useful not only as container for two elements, but because of their natural comparison operators.

Answer (score 0):

**The answer given is indeed a much better solution than your's. I figured i should point out some of your design flaws and give some tips too improve it.**

- You redefined a function that already exists in the standard, which is 
  `std::stoi()` to convert a string to an integer. Remember, if a function 
  exists already, it's OK to reuse it, don't think you have to reinvent what's
  already been invented. If you're not sure search your favorite c++ reference guide.
- The solution stores the data "as is" while you store it as a full string. This doesn't really make sense. You know what the data is beforehand, use that to your advantage. Plus, when you store a line of data like that it must be parsed, converted, and then constructed before it can be used in any way, whereas in the solution the data is constructed once and only once.
- Because the format of the data is known beforehand an even better way to load the information is by defining a structure, along with input/output operators. This would look something like this:

  ```
  struct MyData
  {
     int         num1;
     int         num2;
     std::string color;

     friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const MyData& d); 
     friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& os, const MyData& d);
  };
  ```

  Then you could simply do something like this:

  ```
  ...
  MyData tmp; 
  outfile << tmp; 
  vData.push_back(tmp);
  ...
  ```

  *Their is no question of intent, we are obviously reading a data type from a stream and storing it in a container. If anything, it's clearer as to what you are doing than either your original solution or the provided one.*